# .Xresources syntax

Tags: linux, xterm

This is a sample line from my `.Xresources`:

`XTerm.vt100.geometry: 80x64+240+120`

It works, but I'm concerned about style. One thing is that I see people use things like `xterm*background`. What's the difference? Another is that xterm's man page claims that the `geometry` resource is in the class `Geometry`, but when I put `Geometry` instead of the `vt100`, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two variants of specifying X11 resources in `.Xresources`. You can either specify resources for an application name, or for a Class. Classes are typically named with leading capital(s).

I have in my .Xresources only this: `xterm*color4: #8080c0`.

In the example `xterm`, you can use the parameter `-name xxx`, to change the application name to `xxx`. That way you could have different "styles" of xterms, for instance.
When you specify resources for a Class, it should affect all instances of that class (all `XTerm` applications, no matter the application name).

`*` is a wildcard. People use it to set the resource for many different widgets. Perhaps a button or a scrollbar. If you always want black background on everything, instead of having many rows of X resources, you can use a wildcard.

In your example, you should try Geometry with a capital G: `XTerm.VT100.Geometry: 80x64+240+120` to set it for all your VT100 XTerms. (but not for TEK ones).